# Images are positioned differently in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, position

I have like 5 images - the 2 top ones display fine in both browsers, however the 3 others has a `top` difference of 100px. The weird thing is, the format is nearly identical, except the 1st image has a `top:-15px`, the 2nd one has a `top:-40px` while the 3 others have a `top:-60px`

In order to fix it in FF, I had to use the Underscore Hack, but I don't really like that. (**EDIT:** Just found that doing this will mess it up in IE aswell, dammit ... )

```
<img src="Images/screenshot3.png" class="screenshot" style="top: 40px;_top:-60px;" />
```

Firefox (v4) displays the 3 last images with a `top` property of  `-100px` - Is there any other way around this, other than using "hacks"?

Here is the `screenshot` CSS class, in case you need it:

```
#content-benefits .screenshot
{
    float: right;
    left: -170px;
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

EDIT: Here is my page: http://xskysoftware.com/clickbank/affiliates/

Comment: This question is very difficult to answer without seeing the rest of your page. My hunch is that one of the elements about the images has a `margin-bottom` that is pushing it down. If I recall correctly, IE and Firefox do collapse margins differently.

Comment: @Andrew - Setting the margin:0; did not help either. :S

Comment: Please specify the version(s) of IE and Firefox that you're testing with. Also, have you got a `DOCTYPE` specified in your page: IE will render in quirksmode if you don't specify a doctype, which could very easily result in issues like this.

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, but what about the other elements on the page? Or does the page have nothing but those images? My hunch is that it is another element on your page (probably one that appears before the images in the DOM and may be floated left) that is causing the issue, not the `#content-benefits .screenshot`

Comment: Also, I second @Spudley. Make sure to include a doctype if you don't have one already.

Comment: @Spudley - Testing with IE 7 (the browser HTML editors use, built-in), IE 8, and Firefox 4. In IE8, the issue is the same as firefox. It displays fine inside the built-in browser.

Comment: I already included the doctype. :)

Comment: Do you guys want me to take a screenshot of FF and IE differences?

Comment: Without seeing your page, more code or a working example, we're all just posting guesses.  These cross-browser rendering issues could be caused by anything.  Have you [validated your code](http://validator.w3.org/) yet?

Comment: @Sparky - I am uploading it now. :)

Comment: @Sparky - My IDE has a built-in W3C standard formatter-thingy, but IMO the code it generates is ugly and unreadable for me.

Comment: @Andrew @Spudley @Sparky - I edited the OP, theres a link to my page. :)

Comment: @Jeff: So don't use the built-in formatter.  You have 22 validation errors... just fix them.

Comment: @Jeff:  The validator is showing an extra `</div>` tag.  Find and remove it.  It's showing 18 missing `alt=` attributes.  Add those to your images.  And it's showing 3 missing `type=` attributes.  Add those where specified.

Comment: @Sparky - Just did, did not fix my issue though!

Comment: @Jeff: I would have posted it as an answer if I was sure it would.  (you still have one error though)  However, if you keep it in compliance from now on, troubleshooting will be easier since you won't be introducing other possible new issues.

Comment: @Sparky @Andrew @Spudley - I fixed it by using Javascript to determine if the Browser is IE 7. Would you say thats a too dirty approach?

Comment: @Jeff:  Personally, I do not like conditional solutions to accommodate one particular browser version... more-so when it's a version used by so few people.  If I couldn't find the root cause, I would have cleaned up the code as best as possible and let IE 7 do it's own thing.  That being said, depending on your particular methods, there's nothing inherently "dirty" about a conditional approach.  And you still have [one last validation error](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxskysoftware.com%2Fclickbank%2Faffiliates%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)!

Comment: @Sparky - Check that again, Sir. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If Andrew (first comment on OP) is right, and I believe he is, you'd need to rewrite a lot of your CSS in ways that are nontrivial to determine, in order to avoid using the "hack."

There's no reason I can think of not to just do what you've done and roll with it (other than that if you remove the margin-bottom that's pushing it down at a future date, your layout will break for IE users and you may not understand why.)

The third option is to (instead of using the underscore trick) use conditional comments, like:

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
//stuff
<![endif]-->
```

This is a feature of IE, rather than exploiting a bug, and it might be less distasteful to you.  It doesn't alleviate the problem of making your CSS less unified and therefore more fragile, though.

You will of course have an opportunity to get more specific markup and style advice if you send us a link to your work.  :)

Comment: It means greater than or equal.  Essentially, anything in this comment block is ONLY rendered when it's run on an IE browser that's version 7 or newer.  You can change the number to whatever you like, depending on how far back you're planning to support.

Comment: Basically what you want to do is either define a stylesheet inside the conditional comment or link to an external stylesheet from inside it - a stylesheet that takes IE's finnickiness into account.  :)

Comment: Edited OP with link to my page. :)

Comment: @Kerin - I use the style tag for positioning the different images, so that will overwrite the above. The workaround would be to create a class for each image, but can that be avoided?

Comment: It probably can't be avoided, no.  The alternative would be to give each image an ID (unique, obviously) and define that in the stylesheets.  Use the hash (#) symbol instead of periods to select an ID in CSS.  

Inline CSS is considered "evil" for more or less the reason you're having.

Comment: @Kerin - The Conditional Comment thing wont work for me - nothing happens at all

Comment: @Kerin - I even tried `<!--[if true]>` which always returns true, and it did not fire.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, I'm afraid.  Here's the documentation on conditional comments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Kerin - I have already went thru that page, many times actually. I tried with IE 7 and 8, its not recognizing it.